# jQuery get index of same class objects relative to parent

Tags: jquery, indexing, parent-child

I understand that `.index()` will get the index relative to it's siblings - but that takes into consideration all DOM elements and not with the same class name.
If I use `.index(".some-class")` then it will find the index of the object relative to ALL other objects with the same class in the entire document not the parent container.

I need to find the index of a class object with respect to its siblings within the parent container.

Any ideas how? I'm sure this is simple and I am missing some obvious fact.

Thanks

Comment: Its in the OP. `.index()` returns 2 and `.index(".some-class")` returns 19. I know it should return 0 as it's the first in the parent container, but there's an instance in another container elsewhere above in the DOM

Comment: Have you tried `.index($(this).parent().find(".some-class"))` in short pass element

Comment: That does the same as `$(this).parent().find(".some-class").index()` surely?

Comment: `$(this).index($(this).parent().find(".some-class"));`

Comment: @Satpal shouldn't it be `$(this).parent().find(".some-class").index($(this))`? Because `.some-class` is the collection and you're finding the index of `this` in them?

Comment: @Satpal shouldn't it be `$(this).parent().find(".some-class").index(this)`?

Comment: @Satpal that worked! It's an ugly workaround, but it works. Thanks. Post it as an answer and I will select it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

As from the comments (@Satpal) above the right answer for this questions is below.

```
$(this).index($(this).parent().find(".some-class"))
```

Hope this helps...